# C# XNA 4.0 Check if Any Key is Pressed EXCEPT One

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to write a program in C# XNA and I need to have the program do something if any key except a certain one is pressed. Here's what I want to try to do:

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keys.A))
{
    do stuff;
}
else if (ANY OTHER KEY)
{
    do other stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys()`.

For example:

```
var keys = Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys();
if (keys.Count() > 0 && !keys.Contains(Keys.A)) {
   // Do something.
}
```

P.S. The above code is not tested.

Answer (score 2):

Alexandru provided a correct answer, but I'll go through why it works. It's always useful to understand what you're doing.

Since `Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys()` is an array, you can use the length (or count) to see if a key is pressed:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length > 0)
{
   // Do something.
}
```

And because all pressed keys are stored in this array, you can see what specific keys are in there. That's why you are able to check it with the `Contains(Keys.YourSpecificKey))` method.

You can then use this to check if this particular key is not inside the array using  `!` in a boolean expression.

```
var keys = Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys();
if (keys.Count() > 0 && !keys.Contains(Keys.A)) 
{
   // Do something.
}
```

Since this code is (probably) located in your `Update(GameTime gameTime)` method, it will be checked 60 times per second.